# NSMutuableArray & Core Data not behaving properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have string of photo urls, pertaining to their location (e.x.: googleusercontent.com/photo.gif). I saved that single string (the string maybe holds say, four other urls) to Core Data using the 'binary data' type. When I retrieve the urls from core data, it displays the amount of strings correctly, but does not display the correct data outside of the for loop.

```
// Loop through the photo selection to get the urls
for (int i=0; i < self.tempPhotos.count; i++)
{
    self.photo =  [ self.tempPhotos objectAtIndex:i]; 
    self.image =  [ photo originalImage]; 
    NSString *urls = [image.URL absoluteString]; // <-- here we get the urls and store
    self.selected_urls = urls; 

    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:urls]; 
    self.group.selectedurl = data;   // assign it to the core data object

}

// Now we're out of the for loop, here is where it will not retrieve and log properly. if i put this inside the for loop, it will. why is that? 
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver   unarchiveObjectWithData:self.group.selectedurl];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

If I put the NSLog inside the for loop, I get it correctly. It should look something like this: 
- "googleusercontent.com/photo1.gif"
- "googleusercontent.com/photo2.gif"

When I retrieve the Core Data object outside of the for loop, it gives me this: 
- "googleusercontent.com/photo1.gif" 
- "googleusercontent.com/photo1.gif"

I have no clue why it is working inside the for loop, but it won't work properly anywhere outside, and I feel like I am missing an obvious step. Could I have any help?

Comment: can you put the actual code? there seems to be code missing/incorrect above. For example, NSData doesnt have a variable. one place you have selected_url, in other place it is seldctedurl etc. it is easy to pinpoint issue when we have actual code and all the declarations. I assume this is a declaration issue.

Comment: NSData now has a variable. self.selected_urls is a string declared in the header file, and self.group.selectedurl is the core data object. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `urls` variable is an `NSString`, which you're archiving and then later unarchiving as an `NSMutableArray`, which is incorrect. I think what you're trying to do is build an `NSMutableArray` of `NSStrings` in your `for` loop:

```
NSMutableArray *urls = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.tempPhotos.count];
for (int i=0; i < self.tempPhotos.count; i++)
{
    ...

    [urls addObject:[image.URL absoluteString]];

    ...

    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:urls]; 

    ...
}
```